# How to install/swap Recovery on Redmi 1S, running on CM11

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, twrp

I had install TWRP on Redmi 1S (while running on stock MIUI ROM) and I installed CM11 ROM. It is running fine.

My question is

1) How do I upgrade the TWRP with latest version?

2) How to I change the TWRP to CWM (or vice-versa)?

3) Does CyanogenMod has its own Recovery? If yes, how to get that on my device?

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2: Just flash what you want to have on your device, the old recovery will be overwritten. I recommend the app "Flashify" from Google play store for flashing recovery without computer.

3: About phone > tap build number seven times > press back > developer options > check "update CM recovery"

Answer (score 0):

To update TWRP you can install [TWRP manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jmz.soft.twrpmanager) from the play store. From there you can update the recovery.

To update ClockworkMod you use [ClockworkMod ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager) from the play store.

Another option, you can install them manually by downloading the recovery image and flash them using adb, or [flashify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify), or some other tool.

- [Latest TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/241) (for your device)
- I do not see an officially supported version of CWM for your device.

Cyanogen does have a recovery, which I believe is based off ClockworkMod. I think only officially supported devices have a recovery. As @saloalv said, you should be able to update in the developer options if they have a supported recovery.